# iOS-style picker control in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design, uipickerview

I am trying to create iOS-style picker control in flutter, but this is not gonna work for me. I am attaching screen that I am trying to imitate. Can anyone help me with this design.[image]

Comment: For picker https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html and if you want to see more https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [CupertinoPicker](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html) widget in the cupertino library included with flutter. If that doesn't do what you need, edit your question to be more specific about why and please include your code.

Comment: how do we dismiss a Cupertino picker, also how do we get the value from the picker only when the scroll is complete